# What's the correct way to associate & render data from multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to write some rails code but I am not able to wrap my head around the associations I need.

I have so far:

**Models:**

*team.rb*

`has_many :rosters`

*roster.rb*

`belongs_to :team
has_many :riders`

*rider.rb*

`belongs_to :roster`

**Controllers**
*teams`_`controller.rb*

`def show
  @team = Team.find([:params])
  @rosters = @team.roster
end`

`@rosters` returns the following (in the rails console):

`<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Roster id: 1, team_id: 1, created_at: "...", updated_at: "...", rider_id: 1>, #<Roster id: 2, team_id: 1, created_at: "...", updated_at: "...", rider_id: 2>]>`

**My end goal** is to retrieve the `rider_id` fields, and use those look up the associated row in my `riders` table. This is where I'm struggling. I don't know how to associate my models in a way that allows me access to the data I need.

Additionally, I've read about **N+1 queries** and I feel that I'm already going down that path. I'm also concerned that I'm doing all of this querying on the `teams_controller#show`... I feel like it's doing **too much already**.

If my question needs more code to explain, I'm happy to oblige. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Hi, do you want all the riders for a given team?

Comment: @Satya, yes. I want to get `rider_id`, then in my view, print out data associated with that `rider_id`.

Comment: Ok, if you put the `show` method that @AytanLeibowitz shows you in the answers in the `Team` class, you'll get a Team.show that does what you want. `Team.show.each ...` I would call that method `riders`, though, not `show`.

Comment: @Satya, unfortunately, that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the associated riders using your relationships:

```
def show
  @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  @roster = @team.roster
  @riders = @roster.riders
end
```

As far as your controller doing 'too much already', it just depends on what you are trying to accomplish. I think that this controller is still considered skinny.

Comment: This is coming back as `Undefined method 'riders'`

Comment: I see the problem now. Looking back at your results from the @rosters, <Roster id: 1, team_id: 1, created_at: "...", updated_at: "...", rider_id: 1>. The relationship is either defined incorrectly, or we need to modify the model. Should each roster have a single rider or multiple?

Comment: Not sure I follow. I changed your code to say `@roster = @team.rosters`, instead of `@team.roster`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your current setup only allows one rider per roster.

Comment: I'm looking to have multiple riders per roster. What about my setup allows only one rider per roster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69521/discussion-between-motoxer4533-and-aytanleibowitz).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @AytanLibowitz, I learned that I needed to use a `has_many through:` association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association